# Possible ways to distribute $N$ marbles among $P$ children.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> $N$ marbles can be distributed equally among $P$ children, where $N \gt P$. What's the number of values that $N$ can assume such that $P\gt1$ and  $2 \lt N + P \lt 100$ ?

Now what I have understood from this question is that let's say that the minimum value P can have is $2$ and for this, $N$ can have values from $3$ to $97$ in order to satisfy the condition of $2 \lt N + P \lt 100$ but we can only have even numbers as the acceptable values of $N$ because the marbles($N$) should be perfectly divisible by the value of $P$(Number of children) which is $2$ as it is said in the question that "$N$ marbles can be distributed equally among $P$ children."

Similarly for the value of $P$ being $3$, $N$ will have values which are multiple of $3$ excluding  $3$ itself till $96$.

Now $P$ should be less than $N$, the maximum value that $P$ can have is $49$ in order to satisfy the condition of $2 \lt N + P \lt 100$.

Now I am not able to proceed from here as how to figure out all the possible of $N$ which will satisfy all the above conditions. Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Update :-
For $P=2$ ; $N=4,6,8,........,96$
For $P=3$ ; $N=6,9,12,.......,96$
For $P=4$ ; $N=8,12,16,......,92$
For $P=5$ ; $N=10,15,20,.....,90$
From here I can see that all the composite numbers should be the part of the solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: By your own analysis, you know that $n$ must be a multiple of $p$.  This implies that $(n+p)$ must have form $p(k + 1) ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$  Suppose that (for example) $p = 7$.  Since $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{99}{7} \right\rfloor = 14$, you can deduce that when $p = 7$, then $k$ must be an element in $\{2,3,\cdots,13\}.$

Comment: Not all composite numbers will be in the solution.

Take $98$ for example, it's factors are $1$, $2$, $7$, $14$, $49$ and $98$, those are the values of $P$, unfiltered.

It is a fact the *none* of those factors and be $P$, since all those numbers (except $1$, which is ruled out by the $P > 1$ rule), add with $98$ to be more than or equal to $100$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints...how can we eliminate the composite numbers which will not be part of the solution set. Ok so till now we won't have all the prime numbers a part of the solution set along with some of the composite numbers and 1.